# Quick Clarification about Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Hi thanks in advance for any time spent looking at this question,

I am currently studying brownian motion and am stuck on the following question:

$$P(|B_t| \in C | B_s = x) = P(B_t - B_s\in C-x) + P (B_t-B_s \in C+x)$$

where $B_t$ is standard brownian motion and $ C \subseteq [0,\infty) $.

If anyone can help me through this I would appreciate it.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: For a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $|x|$ is just the distance to the origin. So $|(x_1, ..., x_n)|^2 = x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, have edited my question appealing for more general help as I am fairly new to brownian motion and overlooked that it was just the classic absolute.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(|B_t|\in C|B_s=x) = P(B_t \in C|B_s=x) + P(-B_t \in C|B_s=x)$$
This follows because the event on the left is the union of the events on the right, which are mutually exclusive.

Given that $B_s=x$, then the event that $B_t \in C$ is equivalent to the event that $x + (B_t - B_s) \in C$. If this isn't obvious, I can show it step by step.

I guess that $x + (B_t - B_s) \in C$ can be rephrased $B_t - B_s \in C-x$, although I've never seen that notation before.

So, we have 
$$P(B_t \in C|B_s=x) = P(B_t - B_s \in C-x|B_s=x)$$
Why can we drop the $B_s=x$ behind the conditional bar? I guess it must be the Markov property, though I can't state clearly why.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I believe you can drop the condition as the $B_t - B_s$ is independent of $B_s$ at this point due to the markov properties. I follow you for the first term of the RHS but for the second I'm not sure the argument to get there from $P(-B_t \in C | B_s = x)$

Comment: $-B_t = -(B_s - B_s + B_t)$. Conditional on $B_s=x$, this is $-(x - B_s + B_t) = -x - (B_t - B_s)$. So we are considering the event $-x - (B_t - B_s) \in C$, which can be rephrased $-(B_t-B_s) \in C+x$. Hmm. Makes me wonder if the original statement is correct, actually?